# Admob ARC crash

Tags: ios, crash, automatic-ref-counting, admob

My app crashes. All crashes are different but always related to Admob.

I fixed 90% of problems by putting all Admob code in one signle `.m` file and making it `-fno-objc-arc`
(MOst crashes related to iOS 5.1 when I leave app and return back. e.g. SSO login or just Home button pressed + interstitial. It was fixed disabling ARC for single file.)

BUt app still crashes. It is harder to reproduce.

```
+[GADJavaScriptController sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x283b90
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GADJavaScriptController sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x283b90'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31df788f 0x3664c259 0x31dfa92f 0x31df9915 0x31d54650 0x1c4210 0x1c3cf0 0x34e2960d 0x31dcba33 0x31dcb699 0x31dca26f 0x31d4d4a5 0x31d4d36d 0x357ab439 0x329aee7d 0xa9cdb 0xa9c38)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

BTW `GADJavaScriptController sharedInstance` returns zero results on google.

I use latest Admob 6.3.0

Does Admob supports ARC projects at least with `-fno-objc-arc` ?

What I could make wrong that I get such errors inside Admob?

I am sure I am not doing excess `release` call.

**UPDATE** Got another crash that might be related to first one. According to that [fix](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/UwP-91EQ1-0/8fC3_XZ46PQJ) that I have not tested yet.

[image: NSURLConnectionLOader crash ss]

Comment: Have you added `-ObjC` to your "Other Linker Flags" build setting as described by https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/? Have you tried running your app with NSZombies enabled?

Comment: problem in [GADJavaScriptController sharedInstance]

Comment: Also, the crash when using interstitials and returning to the app is a new crash in 6.3.0, and should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @JesseRusak Is it know bug? I can downgrade to 6.2.1 But I think I tried different versions with no success. I have `-ObjC` in `Other LInker Flags`.

Comment: @Tema Is it a known bug, insofar as I've confirmed it with the folks at Google. We're using 6.2.1 for now. (With the [fix for its most common crash](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/UwP-91EQ1-0/8fC3_XZ46PQJ)).

Comment: @JesseRusak  I got another crash in `NSURLConnectionLoader` Could it be related that issue with `NSURLProtocol` ? I will update question now.

Comment: @Tema It could be related, but it doesn't look quite like it usually does. Have you tried running with NSZombies turned on?

Comment: @JesseRusak No. Thanks for NSZombies. Now it prints that crash is inside of BulletPhsysics. That definitely my bug not related to objective-c or admob